# Create unique DOM elements with D3.js and update them but not append them again

Tags: d3.js

How can I append a `table` with `D3.js` only if this `table` doesn't already exist?

E.g. I want to append several tables to a `DIV`, so if a `table` with `id='table1'` has already been appended, in case it appears again in my list with updates, I would like it to be updated but not appended again as a second `table`.

What I do so far is:

`var tableDiv = d3.select( '#tablesContainer' ).append('table').attr('id', 'table1');`

however in case I try to append a second table with same `id`, `id=table1`, it will create a new DOM element with that same `id`.

Any help is very much apreciated.

Comment: Are you adding tables in response to data? Where's your `data()` and `enter()` functions?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I do: adding tables if they don't exist or update them if they do exist. I am actually using the `tabulate` function from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/jfreels/6734025).

Answer (score -1):

To update already existing Dom elements, you want to select, and then manipulate them like so:

`var table = d3.select('#tablesContainer').select('#table1');`

and do something to the table, e.g.

`table.style("backgroundColor", "grey");`

You are using an `append`, where you should be using `select`.

In case you were planning on creating the tables based on data, use the [`update Selection`](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/):

`var tables = d3.select('#tablesContainer').data(data).style("backgroundColor", "grey");`

To enter and update in two lines of code:

`d3.select('#tablesContainer').data(data);
tables.enter().append("table").merge(tables).style("backgroundColor", "grey");`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I want indeed to update existing DOM elements, but I also want to create them first. So every time I receive an event, if the table does not exit then it is created, otherwise it is updated.

I wonder if there is some way to do both in one line of code, without checking if the selection is empty with `IF`.

Comment: updated my answer accordingly, and I also recommend this tutorial on d3 selections: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/

Comment: Well, the `merge(tables)` function is not really what I want. I just want to update the data inside the same table, not merging it with its updated version. Thanks anyway